# suppress output from `clojure.tools.logging`

Tags: logging, clojure, log4j, rethinkdb

I'm having difficulty hiding the output of `clojure.tools.logging` a library is using. The library is logging an `error` and this causes a stacktrace on `stderr` but it's not an error-level message for me and I can't figure out a way to hide it. I use `timbre` for my own application so I guess capturing the output and re-logging it as a warning or just a debug would be ideal, but for now I just need the stacktrace noise gone.

I've tried rebinding *err* to *out* and then nesting the body within a `with-out-str`.

I've tried a `log4j.properties` file on the CLASSPATH with the root logger's default level set to `fatal`.

I've tried an hours worth of other miscellanea. The logging was introduced to the library here: https://github.com/apa512/clj-rethinkdb/commit/5587bdadaed663fcab3b7c616840dfffec84569a and I can't figure out how to capture it's logger and set it's level or why setting the root logger's level in my log4j.properties is not working.

Any suggestions before I simply do a `java -jar app 2> /dev/null` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `clojure.tools.logging` project dynamically loads a logging implementation based on what dependencies are available on the classpath. Unless you already have SLF4J, Commons Logging, or Log4j as a project dependency, `tools.logging` will fall back to using `java.util.logging` (which directs all output to `System.out` in the absence of any configuration) and putting `log4j.properties` on your classpath will have no effect.

If you want output from `tools.logging` redirected to Timbre, I'd suggest adding `[org.slf4j/slf4j-api]` to your project dependencies and then using the [slf4j-timbre](https://github.com/fzakaria/slf4j-timbre) adapter.

Comment: `clojure.tools.logging` seems really useful, but my solution in the end was to add `[org.slf4j/slf4j-log4j12 "1.7.12"]` to my `project.clj` dependencies and put the `log4j.properties` file in the `resources/` directory with `log4j.rootLogger=FATAL` in it. I'll make do without the logging from other libraries for the time being.